# (standard_in): syntax error - Atom coordinates

Tags: linux, bash, shell

**Dear all,**

I am writing a script that checks, if a certain set of points in 3D space is part of a predefined sphere. I have 500 input files (reduced to 5 for debugging) that contain 66605 x/y/z coordinates of interest.

Problem: I get stuff like

> (standard_in) 2: syntax error
>
> (standard_in) 199993: syntax error

**Code**:

```
#!/bin/bash


radius=20                #radius of the inclusion sphere in Angstrom
sphere_x=-50.861         #x coordinate of inclusion sphere Angstrom
sphere_y=-39.123         #y coordinate of inclusion sphere in Angstrom
sphere_z=-60.123         #z coordinate of inclusion sphere in Angstrom
filebase='frame_'        #base file name of frames that include waters
nframes=5                #total number of frames/files for analysis
nwaters=66605            #total number of water molecules in a single file/frame


for (( a=1; a<=nframes; a++ ))
do                                      # file loop
    echo "Processing frame $a"
    echo "Frame $a" >> results.out  
    grep "O   T3P" "$filebase""$a".pdb | grep -o "T3P.*" >> oxygen_t3p_"$a".tmp
    awk '{print $3 "   " $4 "   " $5}' oxygen_t3p_"$a".tmp >> oxcords_t3p_"$a".tmp
    paste water_name.txt water_number.txt oxcords_t3p_"$a".tmp >> nice_t3p_ox_"$a".tmp  # makes a file "T3P    1337  x.xxx  y.yyy  z.zzz

    for (( b=1; b<=nwaters; b++ ))  
    do                                      #molecule loop          
        water_x=$(grep "T3P $b" nice_t3p_ox_"$a".tmp | awk '{print $3}')
        water_y=$(grep "T3P $b" nice_t3p_ox_"$a".tmp | awk '{print $4}')
        water_z=$(grep "T3P $b" nice_t3p_ox_"$a".tmp | awk '{print $5}')
        dist_x=$(echo "$water_x - $sphere_x" | bc -l | tr -d "-")
        dist_y=$(echo "$water_y - $sphere_y" | bc -l | tr -d "-")  
        dist_z=$(echo "$water_z - $sphere_z" | bc -l | tr -d "-")
        dist_x_2=$(echo "$dist_x * $dist_x" | bc -l) #squared   a²
        dist_y_2=$(echo "$dist_y * $dist_y" | bc -l)
        dist_z_2=$(echo "$dist_z * $dist_z" | bc -l)
        dist_square_tot=$(echo "$dist_x_2 + $dist_y_2 + $dist_z_2" | bc -l) # squares added  a² + b² + c² 
        dist_tot=$(echo "sqrt($dist_square_tot)" | bc -l)  # root sqrt(a² + b² + c²)
        if (( $(echo "$dist_tot < $radius" | bc -l) ))    # distance vector of water to sphere center COMPARED to radius
        then
            echo "Water $b: P" >> results.out
        else
            echo "Water $b: S" >> results.out
        fi
    done
rm *.tmp
done
```

**Explanation**:

Input file format looks like that (*with entries from 1 to 66605 of O T3P and other atoms like H1 T3P and many more*)

> HETATM62640  O   T3P  1679      42.164  51.750 -74.809  1.00  0.00           O
> HETATM62641  H1  T3P  1679      42.052  51.789 -75.759  1.00  0.00           H
> HETATM62642  H2  T3P  1679      42.303  50.822 -74.622  1.00  0.00           H

The first part of the script extract the coordinates of all "O  T3P" and makes a new file that is newly numbered (input file format uses string as identifiers for O  T3P "string", so I have to make a new one with numbers from 1 to 66605). This works so far and my output looks like that: (nice_t3p.tmp)

> T3P   1679    42.164   51.750   -74.809

So all the coordinates of the atoms of interest are now nicely stored and will be used for calculation.

I then calculate the distance vector from the T3P point (xa/yb/zc) to the center of the sphere (xd/ye/zf) and calculate the vector length. Don't bother that I do it in multiple steps, I am new to scripting, especially with "bc".

Finally a the vector lenght should be compared to the radius of the sphere, to check if it's part of the sphere or not and write a simple output.

After this point, I encounter a syntax error in my script and I really can not figure out why. It looks like the first part works with file preparation, but as soon as the math kicks in there is a problem.

Comment: The immediate error message probably stems from some variable being empty. Try run this with `bash -x` to see where exactly the error happens. But more fundamentally this looks like it should not be a Bash script at all. Can you refactor to do everything in a single Awk script?

Comment: I will try running with bash -x and find the error. Thank you. I guess I can't.. as I said I'm really new to these things...